# wget issue to download all files from mailchimp

Tags: wget, email-client

I just want to download all my files from Mailchimp but it did not work.

error:

```
$ sudo wget -r -P https://gallery.mailchimp.com/randomdetailsgeneratedbymailchimp/images/ .
```

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706609/how-do-i-pull-image-links-from-a-website-and-download-them-using-wget but still did not work

error :

```
    Resolving gallery.mailchimp.com (gallery.mailchimp.com)... 34.96.122.219
Connecting to gallery.mailchimp.com (gallery.mailchimp.com)|34.96.122.219|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-07-16 11:44:30 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I just want to import all my images from the past old account of Mailchimp into the newly hosted WordPress wp-content/uploads/2021/0x folder

Edit:
if we embed those images within the Html email template, that works perfectly but can't we download them with wget ?

Comment: I do not see an error only a wget command. And if the creator of that site is worth anything you would need to supply credentials before you can use wget.

Comment: if we embed those images within the Html email template, that works perfectly but can't we download them with wget ?

Comment: How exactly are you embedding these images (and where)?

Comment: we can access those images within the HTML email template anywhere we want. but while we are trying to use wget it shows an error that I have mentioned.